# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter

Tags: php, facebook

Hello I'm trying to make an event on behalf of my users. this is the code I am using to make the request to the API. me/feed works fine. but when I change it to me/events and change the keys and content. its messed up. even copy and pasted the parameters straight from the Facebook developers section.

```
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST',
                            array(
                                'name' => 'hill Billy',
                                'start_time' => '10pm',
                                'end_time' => '3am',
                                'description' => 'Basic Info',
                                'location' => 'street address',
                                'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
                              ));
```

When it's called I get this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1238
```

I changed the code to add the session token even tho it wasn't required for the feed call but it still shows the same error message...

```
       $ret = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'access_token' => $_SESSION['fb_00000000000000_access_token'],
                                      'name' => 'hill Billy',
                                      'start_time' => '10pm',
                                      'end_time' => '3am',
                                      'description' => 'Basic Info',
                                      'location' => 'street address',
                                      'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
```

But to no Evail it still doesnt work

Then I just changed it now to

```
      $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$_SESSION['fb_000000000000000_user_id'].'/events?access_token='.$_SESSION['fb_000000000000000_access_token'], 'POST',
                                    array(

                                      'name' => 'hill Billy',
                                      'start_time' => '10pm',
                                      'end_time' => '3am',
                                      'description' => 'Basic Info',
                                      'location' => 'street address',
                                      'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
                                 ));
```

isn't that what was specified?

Comment: And what does the documentation tell you about the `start_time` and `end_time` parameters …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events

Comment: @DanBaddeley, YELLING AT PEOPLE is not welcome here.  Please make an effort to use proper capitalization and grammar.

Answer (score 2):

While going to ON BEHALF OF in FB Apps.... you should go for Open Graph API with AUTH AU
THENTICATION.. In that first time you will asked for permission/allow option to post ON BEHALF OF.. so if you allow you will get Auth TOKEN/AUTHENTICATION ID... after that only you can able to post/do something ON BEHALF OF...

Pass your access token like below,

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/events?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', 'POST', array( 'name' => 'hill Billy', 'start_time' => '10pm', 'end_time' => '3am', 'description' => 'Basic Info', 'location' => 'street address', 'privacy_type' => 'OPEN' ));
```

Refer the followings...

http://blog.awpny.com/kaiawpny/2011/how-to-facebook-access-token.html

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

You need to pass Auth Token... thats why your error is,

**FACEBOOK PHP API FATAL ERROR: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter**

Comment: i was already logged in and the token is valid tho. i have a seperate script running at the same time that works. as `code` $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST',
                        array(
                            'link' => 'example.com',
                            'message' => 'some basic info' )); `

Comment: pass your access token like this and test please

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/events?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', 'POST',
                        array(
                            'name' => 'hill Billy',
                            'start_time' => '10pm',
                            'end_time' => '3am',
                            'description' => 'Basic Info',
                            'location' => 'street address',
                            'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
                          ));

Comment: i tried ur method as shown above with my new snippit but is still pulling the same error.. and again the other call goes through everytime without the token... this is killing me . and i really appriciate ur help

Comment: please try this for once....

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/events/ACCESS_TOKEN', 'POST', array( 'name' => 'hill Billy', 'start_time' => '10pm', 'end_time' => '3am', 'description' => 'Basic Info', 'location' => 'street address', 'privacy_type' => 'OPEN' ));